# How to Execute couchbase N1ql query through java

Tags: java, database-connection, couchbase, sql++

i am getting a N1Ql query as a string through another service as a input, so i want to execute it by making a connection to couchbase

Comment: You should try to "expand" your question with your approach, so people can help you get it right.

Answer (score 3):

Please follow this tutorial:
https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/start-using-sdk.html

or if you want a more broad view on how to build and app with CB, check out this one:
https://docs.couchbase.com/tutorials/profile-store/java.html

This is a broad question, but here are a few code snippets that might come in handy. First, to connect to a Couchbase cluster, authenticate, and get a bucket object:

```
    Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create("localhost");
    cluster.authenticate("username", "password");
    Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("bucketname");
```

And next, to execute a N1QL query once you have a bucket:

```
        N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(
        N1qlQuery.parameterized("SELECT name FROM `bucketname` WHERE foo = 'bar'"));
```